# How to add DOB field only on customer Edit page but not in registration page

Tags: magento2, registration

I want to display `DOB` field at `edit` and **not** in `Registration` page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable DOB from admin side

> store -> configuration -> Customer Configration  -> Name and
>   Address Option -> Show Date of Birth

Now to hide it from Registration page as your need, you have to comment this line:

Override template **/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml** to **/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml**

```
<?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
    <?/*= $_dob->setDate($block->getFormData()->getDob())->toHtml() */?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: its not good idea to edit default modules na?

Comment: you need to override template check i have updated answer